# Typescript Advanced Type NonFunctionPropertyNames Explained

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was trying to get deeper understanding of advanced types in Typescript one of those types as example is NonFunctionPropertyNames which extracts only a properties of a given object.

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
```

I can understand the first part inside the curly brackets `'{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }'`, we are declaring an object and exclude the properties which extend Function. What puzzles me is the part after the curly brackets `[keyof T]`. This looks like a definition of an array `{...}[keyof T]` but it in fact returns object. 
Can someone explain why only the curly brackets part is not enough for declaring the type, and what is the role of `[keyof T]`.

Comment: Maybe this explanation helps: https://youtu.be/9Swrzqr4MSs?t=1319 :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank you, this made the things clear. So the key was that this constructions (let x:T[keyof T]) is actually returning all the types of the properties and methods inside T, this is not immediately clear. I was under the impression that getting the type of something will require the usage of typeof. 

Can you please give a good example where typeof in Typescript will be used ?

Comment: `typeof` is used whenever you want to get the type of a value. You can use `typeof variable` to get the type of the variable, or `typeof Class` to get the type of the class (the class name represents the type of the instance, not the type of the class (ie the static part of the class))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing there is a type query. If you index into an object type you get the type of that property. For example:

```
type Foo = { foo: number }['foo'] // is number
```

If you are indexing using a union of several properties you get a union of all the property types:

```
type FooBar = { foo: number, bar: string, baz: boolean }['foo' | 'bar']  // string | number
```

If you index using all keys you get the a union of all property types:

```
type FooBarBaz = { foo: number, bar: string, baz: boolean }['foo' | 'bar' | 'baz']  // string | number | boolean
```

But to get a union of all property names you can use `keyof` so the above type can also be written as:

```
type O =  { foo: number, bar: string, baz: boolean }
type FooBarBaz = O[keyof O]  // string | number | boolean
```

The type `{ [K in keyof T]: K }` evaluates to an object type, where the keys are typed as the same literal type representing the key:

```
type O =  { foo: number, bar: string, baz: boolean }
type FooBarBaz = { [K in keyof O]: K } // { foo: "foo"; bar: "bar"; baz: "baz"; }
```

What the conditional type does is make some of those keys, not the same type as the literal type represeting the key, but types them as `never` instead:

```
type O =  { foo: number, bar: string, baz: () => boolean } // baz is a function now
type NonFunctionPropertyNames = { [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends Function ? never: K } //  { foo: "foo"; bar: "bar"; baz: never; }
```

So the new type still has all the keys of the original, but some are typed as the literal type of the corresponding key, and some are typed as `never`. What we want is a union with all the value types of the keys in the type we just constructed, and we can use `keyof O` as before (since the type has the same keys as `O`):

```
type O =  { foo: number, bar: string, baz: () => boolean } // baz is a function now
type NonFunctionPropertyNames = { [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends Function ? never: K }[keyof O] // "foo" | "bar" | never = "foo" | "bar" ;
```

`never` is always removed from unions, so we get at the end a union of just those object keys that were not never.

Make `O` a type parameter and you have a reusable type to get the non function keys:

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<O> = { [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof O]
type Foo =  { foo: number, bar: string, baz: () => boolean } // baz is a function now
type NonFUnctionKeysOfFoo = NonFunctionPropertyNames<Foo> // "foo" | "bar"
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Is there a way to create a more stricter type that considers only own properties and discards the ones inherited from the prototype - "OwnNonFunctionPropertyNames"?

Comment: @VyacheslavCotruta The type system does not differentiate between own props and inherited props unfortunately. If you have a type, all  props belong to it.